# How do I add additional files to a Mac OS X bundle using cmake?

Tags: macos, cmake, bundle

I'm building a Mac OS X bundle using cmake. The bundled app depends on some support programs that are built as part of the same process, so I'd like to copy the relevant build outputs into the bundle as part of the everyday build. (Ideally this would involve the usual sort of dependency checking, so the files would only be copied after they were rebuilt.)

I've tried using `file(COPY...)` and `copy_resolved_item_into_bundle`, but neither seem to evaluate generator expressions, so it's not obvious how to form the right paths.

Is there some way of getting what I want?

(cmake 3.5.0 + ninja 1.6.0. Building from the terminal rather than Xcode/Qt Creator/etc.)